# How can I clear memcachier at deploy?

Tags: django, heroku

Is there a way to clear cache automatically after each deployment?

Or is there a command that I can run to clear it, similar to the command to run a process?

e.g. heroku run python manage.py syncdb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clear the entire cache (regardless of underlying implementation) using [`django.core.cache.clear`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#basic-usage)

> Finally, if you want to delete all the keys in the cache, use cache.clear(). Be careful with this; clear() will remove everything from the cache, not just the keys set by your application.

so one approach would be to [write a management command manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) that makes this call. Create a new module in one of your apps `myapp/management/commands/clear_cache.py`:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.core import cache

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Clears the underlying cache'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        cache.clear()
```

and you can now call `python manage.py clear_cache`. You should look into [Fabric](http://fabfile.org/) for managing deployment as it allows you to write automated scripts to perform all required steps (as well as calling this clear cache script)

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping it would be easier but I guess it dosen't get much easier than `heroku run python manage.py clear_cache`

Comment: Adding to Timmy's great answer, you can also clear the cache with MemCachier through the customer dashboard. A script is probably the easier method though or Fabric.

Comment: One correction - `from django.core import cache` should be `from django.core.cache import cache`